# Find Mongo docs where a value is unique from all other documents using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's say I had a Schema called `MyDoc` with field `key`. These were my documents:

```json
[
  {
    "key": 1
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 3
  },
  {
    "key": 3
  },  
  {
    "key": 3
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  }

]
```

With mongoose, I want to find documents that have a unique `key` value. AKA return all docs where no other docs have its `key` value.

Above, there are multiple docs with `2` and `3`. One document each has a value of `1` and `4`. So in this example, I want to return only the document with `1` and `4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options is via aggregation group:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $group: {
  _id: "$key",
  cnt: {
    $sum: 1
  }
  }
 },
 {
  $match: {
  cnt: {
    $eq: 1
  }
 }
 },
 {
 $project: {
  key: "$_id",
  _id: 0
 }
}
])
```

Stages explained:

1. Group by key to count() the duplicates
2. Match only those that have no duplicates
3. Project only the needed keys

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6evs7AIuRsi)